# Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll SQL Server 2016 location

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dll, ssis, sql-server-2016

I installed SQL Server 2016 Dev with all items and options (included Client SDK).

But `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll` is missing.

Where can I find the dll to reference this dll in a VB project?

[image]

[image: win 7 machine did it this way]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have it in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

Underneath that folder, you should see a specific folder for a given SQL Server version. If you go to that child folder, you can get the dll for that specific SQL Server.

Comment: I did find the dll there.  However, I can't add a reference to it in the VB project.  Visual Studio

Comment: I added an image above.  I browsed to the dll and ticked the checkbox but it wouldn't add the reference.

Comment: OK, I had remove the reference to the missing ManagedDTS and then add a reference to the new dll location.  I can see this is going to cause portability problems for development on non-SQL 2016 machines.

Comment: I also had to update the target framework to version 4.0 or greater to get it to compile.

Comment: On a different (Win7) machine I had the problem again.  On the new machine I repeated the solution here and it didn't work.  I got it to work adding the reference via the 'extensions' tab and that added a different dll (see the image) I added to the question

Comment: help me so much thenks

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but just had this issue today after uninstalling some old 2008 bits. I had this same complaint from SSIS and what worked for me was to go through the Solution Explorer, right click Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS --> Properties and change "Specific Version" from True to False. This let it use the installed version.